# Can't load this .dll (machine code=0x34) on a AMD 64-bit platform

Tags: java

I'm trying to load JNI .so file (that I'm downloaded from Android application using `adb`) as follows:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.load("C:\\libtest_jni.so");
}
```

And I got the following exception

> Can't load this .dll (machine code=0x34) on a AMD 64-bit platform

I'm trying to run my JAVA application with JDK x64 and x86 but still having the same issue.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot load libraries compiled for ARM64 Android (Linux) devices on an AMD 64-bit Windows computer. Both the architecture and the OS must match.

Comment: There are alternatives to solve it?can i use specific VM to solve it?

Comment: @user16634242 loading a library into a different OS on a different CPU is not going to work. You haven't told us why you want to do that, maybe that thing can be achieved in a different way. ([see also](https://xyproblem.info/)) The android emulator should be able to run arm code if that helps you...

Comment: @teapot418, Thanks, is it possible maybe to create VM with ARM architecture to solve it?

Comment: As mentioned earlier, the Android emulator is exactly that. It is freely available and supported by Google. You can replicate it yourself by running Qemu or somesuch but the fact that we had to explain this to you gives me little confidence that you can figure that out by yourself.